# What do you call a phrase or a quote that someone believes in the most ?

Tags: single-word-requests

Eg Be Kind to one another is Ellen Degeneres' ________________ ?

I always believed in the Quote Everything happens for a reason and for the better. So i can call that statement my _____________ ?

Comment: Maybe "mantra".. Welcome to English Language and Usage..

Comment: Do you mean to emphasize the *phrase* that's said—or the *principle* behind it?

Answer (score 2):

> “Be kind to one another” is Ellen DeGeneres' **motto** in life

Oxford Online Dictionaries defines it as

> **[motto](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/motto)**
>    A short sentence or phrase chosen as encapsulating the beliefs or ideals of an individual, family, or institution.

Answer (score 0):

*catchphrase*

> a phrase that is often repeated by and therefore becomes connected with a particular organization or person, especially someone famous such as a television entertainer

(Cambridge dictionary)

> a word or expression that is used repeatedly and conveniently to represent or characterize a person, group, idea, or point of view
>
> Slogan (sense  2)

(Merriam-Webster)

*slogan*

> a word or phrase used to express a characteristic position or stand or a goal to be achieved

(Merriam-Webster)